# View real HTML source in browser

Tags: html, firefox, dom, plugins, internet-explorer

I lookong for some IE or Firefox extension, which allows to browse html source, corresponding to data, shown in browser window right now.

I have large web application with alot of code, generated by JavaScript. I need to extract real HTML code, which I see in browser window right now (View source function shows only code loaded from server, not generated by JS). Most of JavaScript debuggers can show DOM model from browser memory, but I'am need something more friendly, like printable HTML. Does anybody know tools or plugins for IE (preferred) or Firefox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FireBug for Firefox will display the HTML corresponding to what you see in the browser window right now (that is including any modifications made in JavaScript).

Comment: it also doesn't show pseudo-elements like :after and :before http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content

Answer (score 7):

Firefox's [Web Developer extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) will allow you to do this.  After you install it, just select View Source->View Generated Source.

Comment: Yes, but what it won't show you is the generated HTML of a page viewed in an IFRAME.  I had a need for that recently and it's the one variation that's missing (it'll show you the raw HTML, but generated for the containing page only)

Answer (score 2):

You can use 

`javascript:document.write("<xmp>"+document.documentElement.innerHTML+"</xmp>");`
 in IE to view the generated source.
Paste the above and execute in address bar of IE.